# My MQ gas sensors seem to be stuck

Tags: sensors, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

So I've been working on some project for making air quality sensors and ran into a problem. As anyone who has worked with a NodeMCU would know, the chip only has one analog pin. Unfortunately, I have two MQ gas sensors, MQ2 and MQ7, and so I had to follow the guide here to install two analog sensors to the chip: http://www.instructables.com/id/Multiple-Analog-Inputs-on-Only-One-Analoge-Pin/

Now, the MQ sensors are working kinda strange. They output very high values when I uploaded the code from the Arduino IDE and often make no sense when converted into ppm (makes 0). Dunno if it's due to the fact that the heater in the sensors aren't being preheated or what.

```
/*

Multiple Analog inputs on one Analoge pin

Show input of two sensors on one analog pin. 
The vaues of both sensors will be displayed in the serial monitor.

The circuit:
* center pin of both Potentiometer/Sensors attached via a diode to analog input 0
* one side pin (either one)of both potentiometers/sensors to ground
* the other side of both potentiometers/sensors pin to +5V
* pull-down resitor (10k) between analog pin 0 and ground


Created by Vincent Verheggen
Ingenerare

based on:
*example sketch analog input by David Cuartielles
*http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput
*sketch breagan 22 
*http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-with-Multiple-Analog-Sensors/

 */

const int analogpin = A0;
const int mq2pin = 4;
const int mq7pin = 5;

void setup() {


  Serial.begin(115200);
  // declare the enable and ledPin as an OUTPUT:
  pinMode(mq2pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mq7pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    //read from mq sensors

    float mq7_value;
    float mq7_volt;
    float mq7_gas;
    float mq7_ratio;
    float mq7_hold;
    float mq7_ppm;
    //Serial.print("reading mq7...");
    digitalWrite(mq7pin, HIGH);
    mq7_value = analogRead(analogpin);
    digitalWrite(mq7pin, LOW);
    //Serial.print("done!");
    mq7_volt = (float)mq7_value / 1024 * 5.0;
    mq7_gas = (5.0-mq7_volt)/mq7_volt;
    mq7_ratio = mq7_gas/0.18;
    mq7_hold = 24.671324557143727/(mq7_ratio-0.021209244624595787);
    mq7_ppm = pow(mq7_hold, (1/0.7));
    Serial.println(mq7_ppm);

    delay(100);

    float mq2_value;
    float mq2_volt;
    float mq2_gas;
    float mq2_ratio;
    float mq2_hold;
    float mq2_ppm;
    //Serial.print("reading mq2...");
    digitalWrite(mq2pin, HIGH);
    mq2_value = analogRead(analogpin);
    digitalWrite(mq2pin, LOW);
    //Serial.println("done!");
    mq2_volt = (float)mq2_value / 1024 * 5.0;
    mq2_gas = (5.0-mq2_volt)/mq2_volt;
    mq2_ratio = mq2_gas/0.40;
    mq2_hold = 16.177347074757936/(mq2_ratio+1.1016286306095602);
    mq2_ppm = pow(mq2_hold, (1/0.245));
    Serial.println(mq2_ppm);
    Serial.println("----------------------------------------");
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Did you use the electronics also from the mentioned page? Or from the instructable from the link in the script? Mind that the ADC-pin on the ESP8266 has a range of 0-1V while the Arduino has 0-5V.

Comment: I just switched out the potentiometers for the MQ gas sensors and followed everything else in the instructable in the mentioned page, not the script.

Comment: So depending on the potmeters, you're putting between 0 and ~3V on your ADC pin. It only has a range of 0-1V. Furthermore, the gas sensors require 5V to work. You need more electronics to get this working on the ESP8266, but it can be done easily and cheap (a few transistors and resistors will do probably). --> head over to https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: How could I increase the voltage up from the 3.3V to 5V? Is there a way without adding external batteries? Or should I just ask this on the link above?

Comment: SO is for software related questions. You're probably facing a hardware issue. You'll have to switch to another forum. That said, I would use the IO-pins to switch on/off a transistor which drives the sensor. But you'll also have to use a voltage-divider to transform the output voltage of your sensor to 0-1V.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll have an ask around there.